# Uninstalling Ubuntu realtime-kernel

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, apt

I tried the new ubuntu realtime-kernel offered in Ubuntu Pro for a few. Now I want to uninstall it again, so I did the obvious and switched grub to use the old kernel again. However if I try to uninstall the realtime-kernel https://gist.github.com/chaiyujin/c08e59752c3e238ff3b1a5098322b363 after I turned off the pro feature. However it just reinstalls it again after running dist-upgrade.

Comment: What exactly did you do to uninstall?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: The linked page doesn't show any uninstallation of the rt kernel?